# ImageView should be above everything like the Floating Action Button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, imageview, floating-action-button

I have a ImageView in my MainActivity which is on the same position like a Floating Action Button.
I want that the ImageView is above everything like the Floating Action Button.
Currently it looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/ee0aca8d5bc5061d3e437e6d71575ee8

The ImageView is behind the buttons.
But I want that it is always in the foreground, on each site in the app.

My activity_main.XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="Tanzverbot Soundboard" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerView">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:src="@drawable/tanzit"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="50dp"
                android:maxHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="38dp" />

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        </RelativeLayout>



        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to swap `ImageView` and `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`. 
Also, you may try to set elevation for your `ImageView`

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `FrameLayout` instead, with it, the last view in your layout will be always on foreground.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="Tanzverbot Soundboard" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerView">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:src="@drawable/tanzit"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="50dp"
                android:maxHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="38dp" />

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        </FrameLayout>



        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: he needs `LinearLayout` to have `Toolbar` on the top and content below it. And actually `DrawerLayout` itself extends `FrameLayout` if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I m talking about the containerView

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra it still looks like this https://gyazo.com/9275e291f215d92d5e7f2b8740a3d749

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="Tanzverbot Soundboard" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerView">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="50dp"
                android:maxHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="38dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Still looks like this https://gyazo.com/9275e291f215d92d5e7f2b8740a3d749